# setting variable inside if else nested in for loop not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to get highest memory consuming process id in batch file. this so far I reached but it not working.

```
@echo off
set old=0
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='cmd.exe'" get WorkingSetSize ^| findstr [0-9]') do if %%a GTR %old% (set old=%%a)
echo %old%
```

Comment: You need `Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and replace `%old%` with `!old!`.
See `set /?` for the explanation.

Comment: Just for the record, you can only compare up to 2 GB using plain batch

Comment: Thanks Butter, Foxdrive: maximum 2GB, It means batch variable cant hold numeric value more than 2*1024*1024*8 values. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
@echo off 
Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set old=0 
for /f "TOKENS=1" %%a in ('wmic PROCESS where "Name='cmd.exe'" get WorkingSetSize ^| findstr [0-9]') do (
  if %%a GTR !old! (
    set old=%%a
  ) 
 echo !old!
)
```

`Set /?` explains delayed environment variable expansion...

```
Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
the limitations of the current expansion which happens when a line
of text is read, not when it is executed.  The following example
demonstrates the problem with immediate variable expansion:

set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

would never display the message, since the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements
is substituted when the first IF statement is read, since it logically
includes the body of the IF, which is a compound statement.  So the
IF inside the compound statement is really comparing "before" with
"after" which will never be equal.  Similarly, the following example
will not work as expected:

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
    echo %LIST%

in that it will NOT build up a list of files in the current directory,
but instead will just set the LIST variable to the last file found.
Again, this is because the %LIST% is expanded just once when the
FOR statement is read, and at that time the LIST variable is empty.
So the actual FOR loop we are executing is:

    for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i

which just keeps setting LIST to the last file found.

Delayed environment variable expansion allows you to use a different
character (the exclamation mark) to expand environment variables at
execution time.  If delayed variable expansion is enabled, the above
examples could be written as follows to work as intended:

    set VAR=before
    if "%VAR%" == "before" (
        set VAR=after
        if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
    )

    set LIST=
    for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
    echo %LIST%
```